# "invalid pure specifier" when I meant no pure specifier?

Tags: c++, g++

Consider the following snippet:

```
class UltraProbe {
public:
  ConnectProbe *CP() {
    return probes.CP;  // if type == UP_CONNECT
  }
private:
  probespec mypspec; /* Filled in by the appropriate set* function */
  union {
    IPExtraProbeData IP;
    ConnectProbe *CP;
    //    ArpProbe *AP;
  } probes;

};

bool do_one_select_round(UltraScanInfo *USI, struct timeval *stime) {

  UltraProbe *probe = NULL;
  int errno = (probe->CP()->connect_result);

}
```

Why am I getting the error below?

```
scan_engine_connect.cc:592:22: error: invalid pure specifier (only ‘= 0’ is allowed) before ‘probe’
         int errno = (probe->CP()->connect_result);
                      ^
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`errno` is a macro which is perhaps resolved into a function, so we have something like the following:

```
int errno_func() = (probe->CP()->connect_result);
```

So compiler interprets it as an attempt to declare a function.

Comment: Hmm, I've not seen a glibc implementation in which `errno` expands to a function call, though. It's supposed to be an lvalue integer expression. Some manpages actually call it a variable.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't remember where (perhaps on some obscure embedded platform), but I've seen it being `#define`d as `(*__errno_pointer())`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit In VC: `#define errno (*_errno())`

Comment: @AlexD: Okay but VC does not use glibc and the question is tagged [tag:g++] ;)

Comment: This is all of course a tangential point. I'm just surprised I can't more readily find glibc source online with such a definition for `errno`. This is still undoubtedly the correct answer to the question.